# Why would a creature both have carnivore teeth and side-facing eyes?

Tags: creature-design, evolution, humanoid, ecology

So, after a long unplanned hiatus, I have started designing alien creatures again, and one image that eve before that hiatus I could not get out of my head is that of a creature which has both the pointed piercing/shearing teeth of a carnivore, and the side-facing eyes of a herbivore.
The thing is, though, I don't want to just handwave it and say that I'll do it anyway because it looks good to me; I will if I have to, but I would rather have a reason.

Why, then, would teeth that only make sense for an exclusive meat-eater occur in the same species as eyes that only make sense for an exclusive plant-eater?

Now, I've asked questions on here before and subsequently, from not giving enough criteria, gotten unhelpful results, so I'll say a bit more about the creature I'm imagining; It:

- Is vaguely humanoid
- Is at least nearly human-sized
- Has a sense of smell not significantly better than that of a human, although much better hearing
- Has retractable claws on both hands and feet
- Is at least partially warm-blooded
- Is naturally evolved, not having been subject to any artificial genetic engineering, although it is not from Earth or related in any way to any Earth life
- May be either digitigrade or plantigrade (I have not decided), but may not be specifically unguligrade

My question then is this: Why would a creature meeting all the above criteria have both the teeth of a carnivore and the side-facing eyes of a herbivore?

Comment: While it might be generally true that carnivores tend to have eyes in the front, the "fact" that *all* of them do is easily disproved by the fact that sharks exist. Especially hammerhead sharks.

Comment: @KlausHaukenstein also crocodilians, whales,  and dolphins, it is less useful for aquatic or semiaquatic predators.

Comment: Pandas and gorillas are herbivores with front-facing eyes. Crocodiles and falcons are carnivores with side-facing eyes. (And note that humans have pretty good hearing. Animals with better hearing than humans are not uncommon, but having *much* better hearing is quite hard.)

Comment: Perennial reminder - evolution has no end game and no strategy. The only rule is that those who have propagated probably did so for reasons. Sometimes the reasons aren't apparent, are counter intuitive, or nonsensical.

Comment: Predators with eyes on the sides still fixate both eyes on forward targets when hunting. Their eye placement is a benefit for added peripheral vision, but not at the cost of reduced or zero forward vision, like some herd animals.

Comment: Your creature is a praying mantis.

Comment: Bigger carnivores!!!

Comment: In thinking about it, nearly all (if not all) of the reptile and fish kingdoms have side-facing eyes, despite many of them being predators.

Comment: "[side-facing eyes] eyes that only make sense for an exclusive plant-eater?" <-- You're mixing up your causes and effects. Side-facing eyes are not because the animal is a herbivore. Primarily, eyes are side-facing to give 360 degree visibility in order to watch for predators which might eat that animal. Herbivores are, obviously, potential prey, so tend to have this adaptation, but the adaptation is because they are prey, not because they are herbivores.

Comment: I once saw an extremely inbred pug at a pet shop. I won't say that its eyes were on opposite sides of its head, but they definitely did not both look in the same direction.

Comment: @Makyen: Slightly pedantically: herbivores had the _luxury_ of evolving towards 360 visibility not solely because they are prey but also because they are _not_ predators. Had they also been predators, there would be a tension between the need to be a good predator and an evasive prey, which would negatively impact that which drives the eyes to favor 360 visibility above all else.

Comment: How side facing are you trying to get, plenty of predators have eyes that are side facing but also have a large overlapping field of view. It is not a binary state you can be both.

Comment: @AlexP: I wouldn't call [this falcon's eyes](https://birdwatchinghq.com/falcons-in-the-united-states/) side-facing.

Comment: Is it limited to one pair of eyes? Spiders aren't.

Comment: Don't T-Rex and his ilk have both? Either way, how many readers would mind, even if they noticed, so long as you wrote it well?

Isn't the idea of those teeth "only" making sense for meat-eaters backwards logic? Same for eyes…

Could you look again at the Posted want-list and drop all those which don't much matter… as, eg, vaguely humanoid, vaguely human-sized, smell or hearing, retractable claws and being "partially" warm-blooded - whatever that is.

How might any of those matter… or the rest?

Comment: Birds of prey have side-facing eyes but no teeth. Considering that their attack speeds can be up to 390 kph, it does not seem that forward-facing eyes is a necessity for a predator.

Comment: Isn't the point of forward-facing eyes to provide for binocular vision and depth perception?  Make your creature feed off stuff that doesn't require depth perception to hunt,  or give it an alternate form of depth perception by either bobbing/shaking the head or something like echolocation.  Then you get deptg perception and 360 degree vision.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your creature evolved within an ecosystem where it was both hunter and prey.They've exclusively hunted smaller prey but there was one or more other carnivores that hunted them as well.
They've hunted their own prey by sound. Visual acuity was unimportant. But it did help in avoiding being ambushed.

Comment: Came here to say this. It can be a terrifying predator in it's own right, but seeing it has eyes on the sides could be a foreboding hint of what's yet to come upon the scene.

Comment: I was thinking about this idea before I posted the pug thing and it occurred to me that a meerkat is what you describe: carnivore but also prey.  Their eyes are carnivore standard in front, maybe because birds are their predator.  I could not think of a middle trophic animal that had the predator mouth and goat eyes.

Comment: Just wanted to say there are also extinct species to choose an example from. [Allusauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allosaurus) were ambush predators and it was important for them to approximate distance to their prey while sitting in some thick jurassic bushes. Facts taken from some [Russian pop-science article](https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/670960/), so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: You don't even have to look at pre-history to find an example.  Barracuda are a well known species of carnivorous fish who have side-facing eyes and are *also* prey to larger aquatic carnivores (like sharks).

Answer (score 22):

I think the best way to make this work would to make the animal a scavenger. Carnivorous teeth are best to tear and slice decomposing meat, and the side facing eyes would be used to scan for danger as the creature eats.

Comment: pure scavengers are almost non-existent, so it is still going ot have to hunt sometime.

Comment: @John yeah, but PRIMARILY scavengers is enough to explain it.

Comment: @Hobbamok the closest match on earth would be lions, which have very forward facing eyes.

Answer (score 13):

**Your animal is brachycephalic.**

Brachycephaly is a mutation that produces a foreshortened face.  Brachycephalic mammals have shortened muzzle or no muzzle.  I have heard humans called brachycephalic chimps.

Your animal is a brachycephalic carnivore, very much like a pug dog.

[image: animals]

As a visual aid here I have images of a pug dog with eyes very nearly on the sides of its head.  This is not because the eyes have moved but the entire skull is squashed flat.  Next to it as exemplifying the protoherbivore with eyes on the sides of its head is a noble pygmy goat.  On the side and wondering why it is in with these two is a smug wolf, with front facing carnivora standard eyes.

You will see in the comparison of pug and wolf skull that the dentition of both canids is carnivore standard, in so far as there is room in the pug jaw.  This pug skull demonstrates a typical pug underbite which your animal might very well have.

--

Why would a protowolf evolve into a pug?  We know in our world it is because pugs are snorty and friendly but there was artificial breeding involved which your OP precludes.

Why then would a chimp evolve into a brachycephalic human?  Chimps have a wicked attack bite but humans struggle to attack with a bite because our noses get in the way.  The answer is that other adaptive traits came along with brachycephaly.    For your animal, maybe smaller bodies conferred better fitness in lean times when elk prey was scarce but grasshopper prey common?  Maybe the arrival of new predators made side facing goatish eyes helpful?  Maybe the wicked attack bite meant too many pups killed by getting bit, and so the ability to bite hard was selected against?   Maybe snorty awesomeness helps cement social bonds and group fitness?

In any case: pug animals.  Picture would be welcome.  Remember the underbite please.

Answer (score 6):

Many dinosaurs had carnivore teeth and side facing eyes.

[image: dinosaur]

Comment: many (most?) theropods have forward-facing eyes, to my knowledge including the one you've pictured here (*moros intrepidus*). a more specific example than "many dinosaurs" would be helpful here i think.

Answer (score 6):

**While it may be a predator, it could not be the Apex**

There are many animals that are predatory, yet they have their own predator(s) that will hunt them down. For your animal, it could have their eyes like that because they have a bigger, scarier animal that is out to hunt them. Depending on how dangerous the animal is, and what environment your species lives in, it needs to see more areas and be aware at all times. The alternative is that the prey it hunts is quick and stealthy, so it needs to be aware and look around to know where its food is.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming "sharp" teeth - incisors,shark like teeth, etc - with a predator.  However, you are not understanding the *reason* for the teeth.  Teeth evolve to adapt to *what* it eats.  *What* it eats doesnt have to be prey.  A plant can have a fleshy like substance and therefore needs to be torn off, ripped, sliced, etc.

Comment: a few days late, but I believe this a valid explanation.

Answer (score 2):

If you improve the sense of smell I would say "because it is a scavenger". It bullies other carnivores away from kills.

Answer (score 2):

The notion of side-facing eyes for survival amid other predators seems pretty sound.  And since you provide carnivorous teeth as a given, then could it obtain prey by some means other than visually hunting?  Like say:

1. By using a web
2. Listening for movement and spraying poison in a general direction
3. Luring prey to it
4. Scavenging, as other have suggested
5. Observing prey and setting traps or chasing them off cliffs or other semi-intelligent tactics

Answer (score 1):

**It's a whale**

[image]

Your carnivore has eyes on the side of your head because it's a whale. Toothed whales are carnivores. Baleen whales are carnivores. All whales have eyes on the side of their heads.

Answer (score 0):

Vision is not it primary sense. It might have something like echo location for hunting prey at short to medium distances and only use vision for detection at longer distances.

An electrical field sense might also work.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons:

binocular vision helps to locate the distance to the prey animal.  Why would not not need this?

Possibly the predator is MUCH faster than the prey.  Imagine a giant sloth on the ground.  Safe in a tree, but easy prey on the ground.

The predator is also prey, OR there is an escapable but fast moving hazard. Imagine being in a forest where trees fall randomly, but frequently.

The side view eyes are a relic.  The animal lives in an environment where vision isn't used for hunting.  Think bat sonar.